# How does the NOW() function get evaluated cross time zones in Excel Online?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

How does EXCEL ONLINE evaluate the NOW() function when a spreadsheet is accessed from different time zones?  For example, if user PAUL is in London, UK and accesses a sheet at 5PM GMT and user SUE is in NY and accesses the sheet at 1PM ET, what time is displayed for each of them in a cell where the formula is =NOW()?

Is there anyway to set the NOW() function to a specific timezone time?

Comment: [This article from CPearson](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/TimeZoneAndDaylightTime.aspx) covers how to convert a system's local time to GMT, which is what I would use in this case (of requiring the use across multiple timezones).  That way the timecodes have a GMT offset of 0:00 and the times can be converted locally to the appropriate time.

Comment: Is there a way to convert a system's local time to GMT without VB?  I have no idea what I'm doing in that environment.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't access timezone information via VBa.

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3120915/get-timezone-information-in-vba-excel)

However, a work around is here http://www.cpearson.com/excel/TimeZoneAndDaylightTime.aspx

You could change the time zone on your computer though as a hack!

If it's just for 1 persons time zone, and you know the difference, then could just add a N hours.

```
DateAdd ( interval, number, date )
```

EG

```
DateAdd("h", 1, "22/11/2003 10:31:58 AM")
```

would result with 22/11/2003 11:31:58 AM